# Why won't the takeaway system work

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to develop a game, but the system doesn't always work(the one where it tests if you have enough gold). I can't get my head around it, it only works sometimes with the bigger numbers but not with all. Here's the code though:

```
<!--- Game Of War: Ice Age -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Game Of War: Ice Age</title>
</head>
<h4 id="gold"></h4>
<!-- Gain Gold -->
<img src="file:///C:/Users/Hacker/Pictures/GOW%20-%20Ice%20Age/goldButton.png" height="50" style="border: solid; 5px; black;" width="50" onclick="gainGold()"></img>

<!-- Barracks -->
<img src="file:///C:/Users/Hacker/Pictures/GOW%20-%20Ice%20Age/barracks.png" height="50" style="border: solid; 5px; black;" width="50" onclick="training()"></img>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gold = 1000000;
var goldPC = 1;

<!-- Troop Training Variables -->
var mammothCost = 5;
var dinosaurCost = 100;
var mammoths = 0;

function gainGold(){
    gold += goldPC;

}

function training(){
    train = prompt("Train Troops!")
    if (train == "Mammoths") {
        alert("Train Mammoths")
        amount = prompt("How Many Mammoths Do You Want To Train?")
        takeaway = mammothCost * amount;
        if (gold - takeaway <= 0){
            alert("You Do Not Have Enough Gold!")
            training()
        }
        mammoths = amount += mammoths

        gold -= takeaway


    }
}

<!-- SetIntervalSettings -->

setInterval(function renderGold (){
    document.getElementById('gold').innerHTML = "Gold: " + gold;
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @all - The images work fine btw

Comment: img.src=img.src.replace("Hacker","ScriptKiddie"); ....

Comment: @Jonasw why'd you say that??

Comment: you may understand in a few years...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mammoths = amount += mammoths;
```

So you assign mammoths to amount, that was increased with mammoths?? You may want:

```
mammoths += +amount;
```

The additional plus will convert it to a number ( inputs are strings!) So you may also want to add a + before each prompt...

```
val=+prompt("this string is converted to number!");
```

And you may want to stop executing if not enough gold:

```
        if (gold - takeaway <= 0){
            alert("You Do Not Have Enough Gold!")
            setTimeout(training);
            return;
        }
```

The setTimeout is just a styling thing...

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying - it still doesn't work. I'm not sure if you know what i mean so i am going to explain;

Comment: It works(subtracting the gold), but is meant too tell you if you don't have enough gold to train that certain amount. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Thanks for replying so quickly though, 6 Minutes - incredible!

Comment: @TobyBridle oh. even if you pass the if( so wrong) the function execution doesnt stop. updated

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be the `prompt()` function returning a string, which confuses the math that follows. Running the result through `parseInt()` will return an integer.

Javascript gets really picky when it comes to automatic variable type conversion.

Comment: The string thing works and all but it doesn't always popup with the not enough gold alert, but still takes away the gold. Thx for helping out, it took you 9 mins to answer - that's incredible!